# MySql syntax error in wpf application near [__migrationhistory]

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, visual-studio

I am transferring a wpf program from MSSQL to MySql. I have updated queries and connection strings, everything should be good to go. However, when I run the program it crashes, and when I debug, I get this error:

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'MySqlData.MySqlClient.MySqlException' 
 occured in MySql.Data.dll - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
 the manual that corresponds to your MySql server version for the right 
 syntax to use near "[__migrationhistory]" at line 1.
```

I've Googled the error and general migrationhistory information. The table does exist in my MySql database, but I don't see migrationhistory mentioned anywhere else in any file in the program - so how is the syntax incorrect?

I've also tried to ignore this type of error during debug, but it still catches it. Anyone seen this before? Any thoughts?

Comment: See [here](https://www.dbload.com/articles/mssql-and-mysql-comparison.htm) if you are looking for differences between those two databases regarding the syntax usage.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. However, I am trying to figure out this particular error about migrationhistory - it's not referenced in the code, ever, so how does it have a syntax error?